# React ProptTypes - object of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an object, which has dynamic keys(but the values are objects which have same keys):

```
menu = {
    dogs: {
        name: 'some name1',
        url: 'google.com'
    },
    cats: {
        name: 'some name2',
        url: 'facebook.com'
    },
    parrots: {
        name: 'some name3',
        url: 'linkedin.com'
    }
}
```

Suppose I have a component:

```
const Menu = ({menu}) => (
    <div>        
        {
            Object.keys(menu).map(key => (
                <div>{menu.name}</div>
            ))
        }
    </div>
);
```

How to validate the menu prop using PropTypes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do the following using `PropTypes.objectOf()`:

```
propTypes: {
  menu: PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })
  ).isRequired
}
```

Comment: if i pass a plane object ```PropTypes.objectOf({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })``` this throws error and tells *invalid notation inside ```objectOf```*. How to pass Object nested in an object correctly?

Comment: @AlexNikonov You need to use the `PropTypes.shape()` instead of the plain object